# In Doctor Who, who is the oldest Time Lord?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who, before the Time War, who was the oldest living Time Lord in existence?

Comment: The issue I take with this question: once your people become essentially immortal and their bodily age randomizes every time they're renewed, what purpose does age have? We know who the founders were, but they probably weren't the oldest Gallifreyans to become Time Lords.

Comment: I'm tempted to say Rassilon...but maybe I should do some research. BRB.

Comment: Time lords A.) Travel in Time and B.) Have been known to Die and be resurrected (The Master, Rassilon, the Doctor,etc.) Makes this a bit of an indeterminate question without further definition.  Does Rassilon's time 'dead' count?  His time as a 'statue'? How about all of the Doctor's short lives in his confession dial?  I would suggest that linear (non-abrogated) continuous active physical existence (which lets out recycled life, like the Confession Dial experience)..  but even that is murder to try to quantify.  If the Cartmel Masterplan ever resurfaces, that will confuse things even more...

Comment: Old as in was born first or old as in lived the longest number of years?

Comment: @Broklynite - 'Born first' is kind of meaningless with a time traveler.  Biological age makes more sense.. but then there is regeneration.  And then, quantify 'lived' -- did the doctor live in the Confession Dial?  How about Rassilon's time as a statue/trap.  I think people are kind of reaching for a 'internally perceived continuous existence' or something along the lines..

Comment: @SlacklordtheTerrible the purpose of age can be, for example, to determine experience. Even for immortal beings, if both are immortal but one has experienced  5000 years  so far, and the other 20000, it might make quite some difference.

Answer (score 7):

I nominate Rassilon, who according to the TARDIS Wikia, is one of the founders of the Timelord society:

> Rassilon was, alongside Omega and the Other, **one of the founders of Time Lord civilisation** and widely regarded as the single greatest figure of Gallifreyan history. He was generally considered the first Time Lord, though some believed that distinction belonged to his compatriot Omega.

Source: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rassilon

Considering he was still around during the events of *Hell Bent* (Series 9 finale), and Omega hasn't been seen in New Who (yet), he must be the oldest living Timelord.

Comment: He was also dead for quite a while, so does the period he was dead count?

Comment: Was Omega ever seen in Old Who? (since the question says "before the Time War")

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes. A large part of "The Three Doctors" is the Doctor interacting with Omega.

Comment: Unless the Doctor is revealed to be the Other in the TV show, I would tend to agree, except that Rassilon was dead long before the Time War. So, in pre-Time-War terms, we have no idea how long Rassilon lived. Dr. Chronotis was pretty old, but his canonicity is a complicated matter.

Comment: For someone who was dead, Rassilon was quite chatty in "The Five Doctors".

Comment: @Ixrec Omega returned in the [Arc of Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_of_Infinity).

Answer (score 0):

The three oldest Time Lords were Rassilon, Omega, and the other the oldest of them presumably being Rassilon and the other (childhood friends) then Omega their age is unknown but it has subtle hint they say the doctor could be the other reason being in the episode Terror of the Autons of the classic Doctor who you get to see all of the Doctors previous forms it goes from three to two to one but it keeps going none look familiar though so these must be regenerations from before he left his home but as it goes back you see face after face until you see a shadow figure with no visible features but this is still a form of the Doctors but it is said the Doctor came in shortly after the other disappeared and no one ever knew what the other looked like or how old he was they just knew he was there from the beginning and was an advisor of Rassilon so there you have it I believe the Doctor and the other are the same person making the Doctor the oldest Time Lord.